# Picturebox is the wrong size

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, picturebox

I'm trying to add a picturebox onto my Form at runtime, but every time, the picturebox comes out as something like 15 x 15 pixels, even though I've changed the size. Here's the method that's adding in the picturebox. It's located within a class, the `Img` property refers to a PNG file that's already been added.

```
Public Sub Draw(_Position As Point)
    Dim pb As New PictureBox()
    pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize
    pb.Width = 240
    pb.Height = 336
    pb.Top = 10
    pb.Left = 10
    pb.Image = Img
    CardProgram.Controls.Add(pb)
End Sub
```

When I run the program, however, it comes out like this:

[image: Derp]

EDIT 2: I've changed the dimensions to the original image size, but it's still low resolution:

[image]

Any ideas how I can get this image displaying correctly?

Comment: depending on the card game it is easier to just toggle the visible state when you assign a card to it

Comment: So you don't like PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize.  Then don't use it.  Not a lot of users are going to enjoy playing a card game with 15x15 pixel card images btw.

Comment: Your comment has me confused, @Hans. When did I say anything about not liking PBSM.Autosize? I've tried including and not including it, and it doesn't change. And I obviously don't want the image to be 15x15, that's what I'm trying to fix. Did I really misinterpret your comment there?

Comment: There is no "not using it" option.  You probably didn't try PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage yet.  It will perhaps make it more obvious that it is actually the Image property that is the problem.

Comment: I find your tone to be hostile. I tried StretchImage, and that worked in that the picture is the correct size now, but it's at extremely low resolution. I'm not sure how to fix this one.

Comment: what size/resolution is the source image and where/how is it stored

Comment: Dimensions are 71x96, it's stored in an ImageList, taken from a folder inside Debug. I'm not sure how to specify the resolution.

Comment: The problem is that there are 71px in the image data.  you stretched it to 3+ times that.  there isnt enough data for 240 px so it makes some up.  They will look fine at 71x96

Comment: That makes sense, but I changed it to the dimensions as the source image and it's still funky. Are there different measurements going on here? Does 71x96 refer to something other than pixels? Or ditto the PictureBox.Width/Height property?

Comment: we are probably using the same cards...[looks fine on mine](http://i.imgur.com/ZZMXEby.jpg)  Make sure that you didnt change the imagelist `imagesize` property.  It sort of defaults to something smaller than the cards IIRC

Comment: Okay, the `ImageSize` was on 15 x 15, which would explain the problem. But, when I change it to 71 x 96, nothing happens. I've tried multiple different sizes, and it only gets worse if I enter a lower resolution, not better. I'm sure we are using the same cards, I downloaded them from the same source. The images look fine in the browser, just not on the program.

Comment: Got it working. The images were the wrong size in the ImageList, so I reuploaded them, changed the `ImageSize` property, now it's finally displaying correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it's working. For some reason, when I uploaded the images to the ImageList, they were stored as 16x16 images. So I deleted and reuploaded them, then changed the ImageList's `ImageSize` property to the correct dimensions. The code now looks like this:

```
Public Sub Draw(_Position As Point)
    Dim pb As New PictureBox()
    CardProgram.Controls.Add(pb)
    pb.Top = 10
    pb.Left = 10
    pb.Image = Img
    pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    pb.Size = pb.Image.Size
End Sub
```

[image]

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Change you code like below, I hope it will work. You gave to set PB first and then size

```
Public Sub Draw(_Position As Point)
        Dim pb As New PictureBox()
        CardProgram.Controls.Add(pb)
        pb.SizeMode =        PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize
        pb.Width = 240
        pb.Height = 336
        pb.Top = 10
        pb.Left = 10
        pb.Image = Img

    End Sub
```

Comment: Still the same size :/